# Duvida sobre programação paralela

Tags: java, paralelismo

Estou começando a aprender programação paralela, e estou querendo comparar um programa com single thread com um com multi thread.

O que eu pensei foi fazer um algorítimo bem simples que, em um intervalo de 1 minuto, calculasse a quantidade maior de números primos possíveis, e, me mostrasse o último número primo calculado e a sua posição nos números primos, por exemplo, digamos que fosse o número 23, apareceria o numero 23 e sua posição, no caso 9, pois ele é o 9º número primo.

Sem utilizar o paralelismo, o número encontrado foi 774107, na posição 62039. Porém, ao utilizar paralelismo, eu obtive o número 1083757, na posição 84444 (posição errada, a certa seria 84547), acredito que tenha sido um erro bem básico, mas, como eu ainda não entendo muito de paralelismo, não consegui resolvê-lo.

Abaixo segue o código das duas classes que criei, a primeira, é a classe Calcula que só serve pra definir as instâncias e implementar o método run. A segunda é  classe Principal.

Calcula:

```
import java.util.Collection;

  public class Calcula extends Thread { 
      private int x;
      private int quantidade = 0;
      private int ultimo = 0;
      private long tempoInicial;

      public Calcula(int x, long tempoInicial) {
          this.x = x;
          this.tempoInicial = tempoInicial;
      }

      public int getQuantidade (){
          return quantidade;
      }

      public int getUltimo (){
          return ultimo;
      }

      @Override
      public void run() {
        long tempoMaximo=tempoInicial;
        while (tempoMaximo < tempoInicial+60000){
            tempoMaximo = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for(int z=2; z<x/2; z++){
                if (x%z==0) break;  
                else if(z==(x/2)-1){
                    quantidade++;
                    ultimo=x;
                }
            }
            x=x+8;
        }
      }
  }
```

Principal:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class Principal{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        long tempoInicial = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Calcula t1 = new Calcula (5, tempoInicial);
        Calcula t2 = new Calcula (7, tempoInicial);
        Calcula t3 = new Calcula (9, tempoInicial);
        Calcula t4 = new Calcula (11, tempoInicial);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();

        try{
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
            t3.join();
            t4.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        int ultimo = t1.getUltimo();
        if (ultimo < t2.getUltimo()) ultimo = t2.getUltimo();
        if (ultimo < t3.getUltimo()) ultimo = t3.getUltimo();
        if (ultimo < t4.getUltimo()) ultimo = t4.getUltimo();

        System.out.println("Último primo encontrado: " + ultimo);
        System.out.println("Quantidade de primos encontrados: " + (t1.getQuantidade() + t2.getQuantidade() + t3.getQuantidade() + t4.getQuantidade()));
    }
}
```

A lógica que eu segui foi começar cada thread com um valor diferente e ir implementando elas de 8 em 8, para que nenhuma calcule valores repetidos. No fim, pego o getQuatidade de cada e somo, e vejo o maior getUltimo para obter o maior valor. Acredito que o erro seja porque alguma thread esteja calculando um pouco mais rápido, então a quantidade sai errada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que não há garantia que todas threads vão processar exatamente na mesma velocidade. Apenas para fins de exemplo, vamos supor que os numeros primos estão igualmente distribuídos entre as Threads; Por exemplo, se fosse somente 2 Threads: A e B:

Posição : Thread

```
1A 2B 3A 4B 5A 6B 7A 8B
```

Então as Threads irão encontrar, na ordem:
A: 1,3,5,7
B: 2,4,6,8

Porém, não existe nenhuma garantia de que todos irão processar na mesma velocidade, o paralelismo pode causar algo como:

Exemplo 1:

```
A: 1,3
B: 2,4,6,8
```

Exemplo 2:

```
A: 1,3,5,7
B: 2
```

E assim por diante.
No exemplo 1, você esperaria que o retorno fosse a posicão 8, porém como A foi mais lento e processou somente 2 elementos, 2+4 = 6.
E no exemplo B, o resultado esperado seria 7, porém será 4+1 = 5.

Para saber a posição você precisa garantir que todos os números primos anteriores ao resultado máximo encontrado, foram encontrados também: Um jeito de fazer isso é garantir que os números sejam processados na ordem.

Para isso, você pode compartilhar o numero máximo, o contador e o próximo número entre todas as Threads; Você pode fazer isso passando um objeto de controle ou criando alguns métodos estáticos; Em ambos casos defina usando synchronized.

Sobre o synchronized: Se você tiver múltiplas threads acessando a mesma área da memória você pode criar um conflito em que uma thread apaga o valor da outra. Ao definir um bloco como synchronized, você está dizendo ao Java que somente um pode acessar por vez, se outro tentar acessar esse mesmo método terá de aguardar.

Fica algo como:

```
 public class Calcula extends Thread { 
      private static quantidade = 0;
      private static int ultimo = 0;
      private static int proximo = 2;
      private long tempoInicial;

      public Calcula(long tempoInicial) {
          this.tempoInicial = tempoInicial;
      }

      public int getQuantidade (){
          return quantidade;
      }

      public int getUltimo (){
          return ultimo;
      }

      private static synchronized void primoEncontrado(int n){
          quantidade += 1;
          if (n > ultimo) ultimo = n;
      }

      private static synchronized int proximo() {
         return proximo++;
      }

      @Override
      public void run() {
        long tempoMaximo=tempoInicial;
        int x;
        while (tempoMaximo < tempoInicial+60000){
            x=proximo();
            tempoMaximo = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for(int z=2; z<x/2; z++){
                if (x%z==0) break;  
                else if(z==(x/2)-1){
                    primoEncontrado(x);
                }
            }

        }
      }
  }
```

(Pode precisar de alguns ajustes, escrevi sem testar).

Dessa forma a cada Thread que quiser analisar um novo número, irá pedir ao **proximo** pelo próximo número na "fila", e ao encontrar é reportado ao **primoEncontrado**
Em teoria isso vai reduzir a velocidade levemente porque o processamento pesado está em fazer os 2 loops, porém é uma consequência da necessidade de processar na ordem.